# Magento 1.x : Accessing Magento Rest Api as Admin

Tags: magento-1, api, rest-api, role

I am trying to access magento rest api with following script, but is uses default guest role to access, so I cannot access orders and other stuffs. How can I access Magento Rest api as admin.

```
<?php

$callbackUrl = "http://192.168.1.144/o2/api/rest/orders";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl =
"http://192.168.1.144/o2/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" .
urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://192.168.1.144/o2/admin/oAuth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://192.168.1.144/o2/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://192.168.1.144/o2/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '**********************';
$consumerSecret = '**********************';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) &&
$_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
   $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
   $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION
: OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
   $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret,
OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
   $oauthClient->enableDebug();

   if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
       $requestToken =
$oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
       $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
       $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
       header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' .
$requestToken['oauth_token']);
       exit;
   } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
       $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
       $accessToken =
$oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
       $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
       $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
       $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
       header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
       exit;
   } else {
       $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
       $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/orders";
       $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
       $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
       print_r($productsList);
   }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
   print_r($e);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you created an admin role for REST API in the backend?

Comment: Yeah, I have created one and assigned it to user

Comment: @Alvi_1987 - do you recall how you resolved this?